# Javascript to create a chart from a dynamic table

Tags: javascript

I'm relatively new to Javascript and would require some assistance in creating a chart from a dynamic HTML table.  The number of rows may vary based on received data.  Unfortunately, my chart is populating only the 1st row of data.

Below is sample of my code, so far, and the result.

thanking you all.

CODE:

```
  //Chart for Table 1
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  //load the Google Charts Visualization 
  $.getScript('https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js', function () { 
  });
  
  //when anything in the Table changes, update the bar chart
  $('.Proj').on('change', function() { 
  
    //Chart update code
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
      
      //get the table values from the hidden totals fields
        var contract = String($('.Contract input').val());
        var periodrevenue = parseInt($('.PeriodRevenue input').val());
        var periodcost = parseInt($('.PeriodCost input').val());
        var periodmovement = parseInt($('.PeriodMovement input').val());
      
      
      //store the fields into the array
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Contract','Period Revenue','Period Cost','Period Movement'],
        [contract, periodrevenue, periodcost, periodmovement],
      ]);
     
      //set the chart title
      var options = {
        title: 'Contracts Review',
        isStacked: true
      };
      
      //update the bar chart
       var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart1_values'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  });
});
```

[Image of table and chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wry15.png)

Comment: Yes, but what is your question?

Comment: How to modify the JS so that it draws the chart for every row and not just the 1st one?

Comment: I haven't worked with google chars before but i assume that you only give it one set of values here `var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Contract','Period Revenue','Period Cost','Period Movement'],
        [contract, periodrevenue, periodcost, periodmovement],
      ]);`, I would assume that at this point you need to iterate your table to get all the values and add them to the array

Comment: exactly, but i'm not too sure on how to go about doing that part.